# What's the difference between the new StanfordNLP native Python package and the python wrapper to Core-NLP?

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

Can anyone shed some light on the difference between the neural pipeline used in the new native Python StanfordNLP package: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/

and the python wrapper to the Java coreNLP package https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/?

Are these two different implementations? I saw that the StanfordNLP package has native neural implementations but also had a wrapper to the CoreNLP package and was wondering why you would need this wrapper if everything was migrated to python anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two systems are completely distinct. The Python-native neural pipeline roughly corresponds to [Universal Dependency Parsing from Scratch](https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/qi2018universal.pdf), with the Tensorflow parser used there reproduced in PyTorch. It provides a fully neural pipeline for many languages from sentence splitting through dependency parsing, exploiting [UD](https://universaldependencies.org/) resources, but doesn't (at present) support other things such as NER, coreference, relation extraction, open IE, and hand-written pattern matching, and is only trained on UD resources. [CoreNLP](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P14-5010), which you can use through this or other Python wrappers, does provide all of these other components for a handful of languages, and some models, including English, are trained on much more data. It has the advantages and disadvantages of many pre-neural components (fast tokenizer! purely heuristic sentence-splitting). Most likely, if you're working with formal English text, you'll currently still do better with CoreNLP. In a bunch of other circumstances, you'll do better with the Python stanfordnlp.